# Footer with 100 % on Ipad

Tags: css, ipad, footer

I need some help. I have made this side in Joomla, and cant get my footer to have a 100% width on an Ipad. Its like it wont get furder then my footer content. 
Can some one please help me adding the right css?

My website is: [www.webkjaer.dk](http://www.webkjaer.dk)
And here is the [Ipad emulator](http://ipad-emulator.org/)

Comment: The left side of the footer is showing correct, but the right side needs 20-50 px more. but still, i want the css to have 100% not pixels.

Comment: The footer does have 100% width on the ipad (as i can see from the emulator) but the page has some extra margin on the right that makes is scrollable... In any case, share your css code so we can take a loot at it. At the moment, we can't see what you did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your website head

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```